# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un trigger update para una sola persona?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una bitácora de personas donde se ingresan los registros personales de una persona y su usuario y correo, para la parte de registro me guarda todos los datos bien, pero al momento de hacer un trigger de update me hace la modificacion en todas los registros de esa persona especificamente lo que es la parte de usuario y correo, estoy usando este codigo para hacer el trigger de Update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Usuarios_AModificar 
AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE bitacorapersonas 
SET usuarioNuevo = NEW.usuario, correoNuevo = NEW.correo,   
correoViejo=old.correo, activacionNueva = new.activacion, 
activacionVieja=old.activacion WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula
```

Mis tablas son las siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_session` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activacion` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `token_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password_request` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_tipo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuarios_cedula` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` text NOT NULL,
  `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No sé por qué al actualizar un dato de una persona ejemplo lo que es correo y usuario la primera vez lo hace bien y cuando modifico por segunda vez el primer registro tambien se cambia.